# One function changing another function's local variable?

Tags: javascript, local-variables

I had a problem with some JavaScript functions that had me scratching my head for about an hour until some well-placed alert()'s revealed something which surprised me. One function was changing another function's local variables, it seems. I wrote a simple test script:

```
function first() {
    msg = "1111";

    second();

    alert(msg);
    }


function second() {
    msg = "2222";
    }
```

When I call first() I'd expect to get an alert box saying "1111" but I get "2222" instead. How is it that second() is affecting a local variable belonging to first()? Am I missing something or is this a bug?

I'm using Firefox 12.0.

Comment: That's not local without `var msg...` inside the functions.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values%2C_Variables%2C_and_Literals#Variable_scope (the whole guide is worth a read if you are new to JavaScript)

Comment: I used to be really confused by variable scope, and then I learned to [shut up and love the closure scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variable is only local when the var statement is used:

```
var msg = "1111";
```

Otherwise the value escapes into the global scope.

Comment: Not to be picky, but the `"1111"` and `"2222"` are also a little odd.

Comment: Haha, in several years on and off with JavaScript (I do it for hobby not for work) this had completely evaded me until now. I've put `var` in front of `msg=...` and it works as expected. Thanks!

Comment: Just think of it as without the `var` to declare the variable, it assumes the variable is present in the global scope.